# node close Arduino serialport connection before doing anything

Tags: node.js, arduino, node-serialport

I'm trying to use **node** to print the Serial from *Arduino uno* connected to USB

I have a file *script.js*:

```
    var SerialPort= require("serialport");

    SerialPort.list(function(err,ports){
            ports.forEach(function(port){
            console.log(port.comName);
            console.log(port.manufacturer);
        });
        });

    var port= new SerialPort("/dev/cu.usbmodem641",{
            baudRate: 9600,
            parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('n')
        });


    port.on('open',function(){
    console.log('opened');
        });



    port.on('close',function(){
            console.log('closed');
        });
port.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data);
    });

port.on('error',function(error){
        console.log("Errore: "+error);
    });

console.log(":-)");
```

I **run** *sudo node script.js* while *Arduino* has `Serial.println(1);`

on **terminal** I see:

`opened
closed`

If I open **Arduino IDE**'s serial monitor it correctly works!

Why my serial port doesn't stay opened?

Comment: Couple things to consider, not necessarily the answer though:
1. Is this for sure the correct COM port
2. It could be that the Arduino IDE is forcing the port to close so that it can gain control over the Arduino. If possible, try to run the program with the Arduino IDE closed
Also looks like it may be solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735047/node-serialport-only-communicates-with-arduino-if-another-app-has-already-connec?rq=1

Comment: 1. Yes, I'm **sure** (Arduino IDE tell is that AND serliaport list indicates that as well)  2. I attemped several times with IDE opened, close, open IDE after node and viceversa  3. I tried that solution

Comment: Perhaps it is the line `parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('n')`. This will look for the character "n" not newline. This may be what you intended but it may need to be `parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\n')` to parse on newline instead of "n".

Comment: You're right I meant "\n", corrected but still not work. The fact is that the port closes as it is opened leaving non time do to anything!

Comment: Very strange, I am sure this is caused by the Arduino rebooting when it is attached to a serial port so that it can enter the bootloader. I'm unsure of why implementing the solution I linked to before isn't solving the issue, perhaps extend the delay to ensure that the bootloader has executed and the code is running. Is there any noticeable difference when using this solution?

Comment: I tries up to 10 seconds (I imagine is enough, when it as rebooted its led blink a couple of time) when implemented this solution it open (and soon close) the connection two times (I printout "open" and "close")

Comment: I am trying http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection, now **surely** it does not reset, but still not remain open!

Comment: Although it shouldn't reset, it says on that page that it may still. This is because of the variation in current delivered by the FTDI chip. Not to say that it is, but it may. One thing to try is to add  
`dataBits: 8, 
      parity: 'none', 
      stopBits: 1, 
      flowControl: false 
 });` The flow control bit should force the computer to leave DTR alone, which may help.

Comment: When it reset it blinks when open serial in IDE now it does nothing so I think it correctly resets! **tried** your parameters but nothing changes! I also tried *authOpen* false

Comment: Interesting, sounds like you are correct in that it is not resetting. http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Python although this is for python, it may be worth quickly implenting to ensure that your Arduino serial comm is working in general outside of the Serial Monitor.

Comment: Ok *python* works correctly! Also *screen* command works!

Comment: Ah, it may perhaps be the layout of your NodeJS code. Try moving your `port.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data);
    });` inside of `port.on('open',function(){
    console.log('opened');
        });` so to refactor `port.on('open',function(){
    console.log('opened');
port.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data);
    });
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *give up* and did this in *python*!

https://github.com/fvalle1/Arduino/